# How to guarantee test server is killed?

Tags: gnu-make

I'm a big fan of Python's try/finally and the builtin trap command in various shells. I have a Make target to which I would like to apply the same sort of logic. Suppose I have this target and dependencies:

```
test : start-server run-test-group-1 run-test-group-2 stop-server
```

If tests fail during the run-test-* phases, the stop-server actions won't execute. Is there a way to guarantee the stop-server actions are executed, even if "-k" is not given? I realize I could place "-" before the relevant command(s) in in the run-test-* actions, but I think that would cause make to exit with a 0 status, causing the controlling process to think the tests succeeded. I still want the parent process to know the tests failed.

Comment: I think you can't use the dependency mechanism and at the same time have make say something completely different about the rule success except by carrying around exit stati in your own variable and ignoring recipe return values with `-`. BTW I personally would never rely on the written order of recipe fulfillment like you did there, even if make guarantees that (which I think doesn't hold as soon as you go parallel)

Comment: Thanks. I understand execution order goes out the window with -j but as I control the invocation, that's a problem I can live with. I guess I'll probably have to embed the individual sets of actions from the other targets into this target's actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the shell trap mechanism instead and run make recursively, perhaps? Like this:

```
test:
    trap EXIT ERR "$(MAKE) stop-server"; \
    $(MAKE) start-server && \
    $(MAKE) actual-test

actual-test: run-test-group-1 run-test-group-2
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like an excellent suggestion. I already split into three separate recursive submakes, but had to dig into the output looking for evidence of success or failure. Not sure why I didn't think to use trap. Perhaps my general distaste for the "; \" hack needed to guarantee all statements are run by a single process.

Comment: GNU Make has the handy .ONESHELL pseudo-target.  I abstain from using it in answers because its effect is global, but if you are not stuck maintaining legacy makefiles it's worth taking a look at.

Comment: This formulation is the best as it also makes the serial nature of the commands explicit. Relying on the ordering of dependencies for this is not good style (that breaks under parallel make. You do use parallel make don't you?)